# TYPO3 - Page not found when accessing page via http

Tags: iis, typo3, typo3-10.x

I have a TYPO3 10.4.16 page on a Windows Server 2019 IIS 10 Server.

The page is accessible via https. I have created a redirect on my IIS Server to rewrite the URL from http to https. When I enter the page with http on a device, where I never entered the URL before, I get the error `Page Not Found. The page did not exist or was inaccessible. Reason: No site configuration found.`

When I enter the page with http on a device, where I entered the URL with https before, the redirection to https works.

How can I edit my TYPO3 site configuration to handle also the http version of the page? Or how can I create a redirect in TYPO3 from http to https?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the device where you never used the URL and the other device is that the browser remembers that https is available for that domain and always prefers that.

So obviously the redirect from http to https in the IIS settings is not working correctly. To check that the redirect is really working you can use curl on the command line:

`curl -IL http://domain.tld`

`-I` shows only the header data
`-L` follows redirects

There is no way to handle the https redirect within the TYPO3 configuration.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. Is it possible to create a seperate page in TYPO3 for handling the http request? For that specific page I create an own site configuration with entry point http://www.domain.tdl instead of https://www.domain.tdl ?